# Add quotes to each element in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

How to add quotes to each element in a list?
For example, we have a list as:

```
    list = {{k, \[Beta], Subscript[A, 1], Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[b, 
   2]}, {k, \[Delta], \[CapitalTheta]}}
```

How to get

```
{"{k, \[Beta], Subscript[A, 1], Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[b, 
   2]}", "{k, \[Delta], \[CapitalTheta]}"}
```

Comment: Is this what you need? `"\"" <> ToString[InputForm@#] <> "\"" & /@ list`?

Comment: also `ToString[InputForm[#]] & /@ list`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally you would use ToString for this. That will result in a different formatting for Subscript elements, however. You can wrap the items in InputForm first:

```
ToString@*InputForm /@ list
```

or

```
ToString /@ InputForm /@ list
```

Answer (score 3):

My attempt is the following:

```
ToSubscriptHoldForm[expr_?VectorQ] := Block[{asymb, asub},
asymb = Array[Subscript[ToExpression["a"], #] &, 2, 1];
asub = Array[Subscript[ToExpression["a"], #] &, 2, 1, HoldForm[Subscript]];
Which[Length[expr] === 1, expr, Length[expr] === 2, ReplaceAll[Thread[asymb -> expr]][asub], Length[expr] > 2, expr]]
```

Test:

```
list2 = ReleaseHold@Map[ToString, Map[Composition[ToSubscriptHoldForm, Level[#, {1}] &], list, {-2}], {-1}]
```

[image]

Go back to your list:

```
Map[ToExpression, Map[InputForm[#] &, list2], {-1}] === Map[InputForm[#] &, list]
(*True*)
```

Your list:

```
Map[ToExpression, Map[InputForm[#] &, list2], {-1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Based on the expected output provided in the original post, I thought that each of the two lists needed to be string-ified, not the lowest level elements. Maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: You're right @lericr, I misunderstood and went a little further. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
 {{k, b, Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[b, 2]},
  {k, d, p}}
```

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[list, x_ :> ToString @ InputForm @ x]
```

> {"{k, b, Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[b, 2]}", "{k, d,
> p}"}